# Operator norm of family matrix products

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, operator-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Consider the following problem:
Let $A(\xi),B(\xi),C(\xi)$ be three families of matrices indexed by $\xi\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $$\sup_{\xi\in\mathbb{N}}\|B(\xi)\|_{op}<+\infty,\quad \sup_{\xi\in\mathbb{N}}\|C(\xi)A(\xi)\|<+\infty$$ and every $A(\xi)$ is self-adjoint, diagonal and uniformly bounded. Is it true that $$\sup_{\xi\in\mathbb{N}}\|A(\xi)B(\xi)C(\xi)\|_{op}<+\infty? $$
I have tried many different matrix-norm inequalities and identities, such as the ones in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.08299.pdf
But they don't seem to work as I can't use that $A(\xi)^{-1}$ is uniformly bounded...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is false, I found the following counter-example:
\begin{align*}
        A(\xi) = \begin{pmatrix}
            1&0 \\ 0&\xi^{-1}
        \end{pmatrix},B(\xi) = \begin{pmatrix}
            0&1 \\ 0&0
        \end{pmatrix}, C(\xi) = \begin{pmatrix}
            1&1 \\ 0&\xi
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}